# Ubuntu Raid 1 mounting and size are off

Tags: ubuntu, raid, mdadm

Ubuntu 20.04.4, 2 new 10 TB drives, been having issues getting it mounted and using the full size.

`lsblk`

```
sda                         8:0    0   9.1T  0 disk  
└─sda1                      8:1    0   9.1T  0 part  
  └─md0                     9:0    0   9.1T  0 raid1 /storage
sdb                         8:16   0   9.1T  0 disk  
└─sdb1                      8:17   0   9.1T  0 part  
  └─md0                     9:0    0   9.1T  0 raid1 /storage
```

`df -h` shows 2.0 T instead of 9.1T

```
/dev/md0                           2.0T   81M  1.9T   1% /storage
```

`mdadm --detail --scan`

```
ARRAY /dev/md/server:0 metadata=1.2 name=server:0 UUID=cc6a23e7:f6ae3752:7270e701:41a8ac2f
```

I've had issues mounting it.  Sometimes it is `/dev/md0` sometimes `/dev/md127`.  Also, showing 2TB and runs out of space.  When I mount it, sometimes it just mounts to my home drive.

Comment: This is all very mysterious. What do you mean with "sometimes it just mounts to my home directory"? What exactly are you executing in that situation?

Comment: If I `sudo mount /dev/md0 /storage` and start transfers, my nvme will fill up.

Comment: did you resize the raid? which filesystem is on it? did you resize the filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

I had previously created the ext4 filesystem.  I went ahead and did it again, though it said it already had an ext4 filesystem.  It's working now, though I don't know if it was the mounting or the file system.  Thanks frostschutz.